# Unpickling bytea columns from Psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, pickle, psycopg2

I am storing pickled objects in a PostgreSQL database. Originally I thought this was a bad idea, but they are seldom accessed and from what I've learned apparently TOAST makes the performance impact minimal for storing big blobs in a relational database.

When you `INSERT` or `UPDATE` a `bytea` column it is simple. Just construct a `psycopg2.Binary` and pass it to the `execute` call on the cursor object. In my case, it's a pickled object.

Whenever you do a `SELECT` and get back a `bytea` column you wind up with a python `buffer` object. In other words, you can't just do a `pickle.loads` or a `pickle.load`. The best I've come up with is using `StringIO`

```
import psycopg2
import cPickle as pickle
import cStringIO as StringIO

conn = psycopg2.connect(user='postgres',database='postgres')

cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('Select %s', (psycopg2.Binary(pickle.dumps({'foo':'bar'},-1)), ))

result, = cur.fetchone()

cur.close()
conn.rollback()

result = StringIO.StringIO(result)

print pickle.load(result)
```

What's the cost of this? Are the `StringIO` objects just shallow copies of the original `buffer` object? Is there a more practical way of doing this?

I'm using Stackless 2.7.5 if it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that using cStringIO and cPickle is many times faster and is the best option in this case. Full writeup here http://www.hydrogen18.com/blog/unpickling-buffers.html

Comment: @RomanPekar Thank you ! I was surprised by the results I can't accept my own until a few days.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to create `StringIO` object, you can just create `str` from your `result` and then read it:

```
>>> pickle.loads(str(result))
{'foo': 'bar'}
```

Don't know about `cStringIO`, but `StringIO` do this anyway (taken from `StringIO`):

```
def __init__(self, buf = ''):
    # Force self.buf to be a string or unicode
    if not isinstance(buf, basestring):
        buf = str(buf)
```

**update**: tested it with `timeit`:

```
>>> timeit('s = pickle.loads(str(result))', 'import cPickle as pickle;from __main__ import result', number=100000)
1.2336693825245675
>>> timeit('s = pickle.load(StringIO.StringIO(result))', 'import cPickle as pickle; import cStringIO as StringIO;from __main__ import result', number=100000)
1.0089504222504786
```

So your approach a bit faster than creating string from buffer

Comment: I looked into `cStringIO`. If you pass it the `cString.StringIO` function an object, then you get back a `cString.StringI` object. It uses the C function `PyObject_AsReadBuffer` to create a read-only view of the object passed in. So it's a shallow copy when `cStringIO` is used.

Comment: @EricUrban so your approach looks like best for that